# Does nginx check the expiration date of the server certificate?

Tags: nginx, pyopenssl

Does nginx check the expiration date of the server certificate?
If the nginx has the feature, I would like to enable or disable the feature.

Comment: Do you mean the certificate that it's serving via `ssl_certificate` or validating an SSL endpoint of `proxy_pass`?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining sufficiently. via ssl_certificate.

Answer (score 1):

nginx does not care about the expiration and is perfectly happy to serve self-signed certificates as well. As long as the certificate key pair is syntactically valid, you are good to go (in the sense that it will technically work, naturally browsers and most clients will not accept it without overriding the checks).

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot!